# Cordova & Braintree: PayPal login window is blank

Tags: javascript, cordova, paypal, braintree

I use PayPal with Braintree. They have a simple "dropin": A PayPal button that opens a small new browser window for the user to log in to PayPal.
This works  great on desktop and mobile versions of my site.

But when I run the site compiled with Cordova the popup is always fullscreen and blank (just white, no login fields).

I tried to hook cordova-plugin-inappbrowser:

```
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open
```

But then I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'focus'

Comment: were you able to find any solution for this? I have facing similar issue, it goes black after the login if open in InAppBrowser, but works in both Desktop Browser and Mobile Browser.

Comment: Sadly not. They say they don't support Cordova.

Comment: Same here, they said not possible to help in hybrid apps. Now I will have to replace it with Native SDKs. Thanks for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have just published [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-popup-bridge), a fork of `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`, which adds support for Braintree's PopupBridge functionality.

This enables web pages using Braintree's JS SDK (and therefore Web Drop-in) to function with Cordova-based Android and iOS apps and support PayPal payments.